# Javascript prototype setter and getter

Tags: javascript

Working with javascript prototype pattern, how do I set default values for options then overwrite those value with assigned parameters?

```
var myController = function() {
    //constructor
}

myController.prototype.options = {
    element: '.el',
    selector: '.selector'
};

myController.prototype.init = function(args) {
    console.log(this.options.element);
    console.log(this.options.selector)        
};

var params = {
   element: '.test'
};
myController.init(params);
```

Should output

```
'.test'
'.selector'
```

since `params.element` should overwrite the `options.element` property.

Comment: you aren't doing anything with `args` in your `init`

Comment: @charlietfl I am actually stuck on that part.

Comment: Are you trying to initialize the prototype or future instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I hope you'll like. I've written it according to your requests.

```js
var myController = function(){
 //constructor
}

myController.prototype.options = {
 element: '.el',
 selector: '.selector',
 anotherthing: 'blah',
 anotherotherthing: 'blah blah'
};

myController.prototype.init = function(args){
 //woah...
 //Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object) creates an array of the object's properties
 for(var c = 0; c < Object.getOwnPropertyNames(args).length; c++){
  //loops through every property of this.options
  for(var d = 0; d < Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.options).length; d++){
   //checks if the current property names are equal...
   if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(args)[c] === Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.options)[d]){
    //... and if they are it assigns the value of the args property to the this.options property
    this.options[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(args)[c]] = args[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(args)[c]];
   }
  }
 }
 
}

//and to prove it works
var thing = new myController();

var params = {
 element: '.test', //will replace thing.options.element
 anotherthing: 'was replaced', //will replace thing.options.anotherthing
 something: 'that won\'t do anything' //will do nothing, isn't a property of thing.options
};

thing.init(params);
console.log(thing.options);
```

Run the snippet and then check the console.

Comment: The second code is what I wanted but is there a way to loop it instead of assigning them one by one? It would be useful if there are alot of objects on the options.

Comment: @user1781041 I hope you like it!

Comment: @user1781041 No problem! Happy to see someone satisfied